# MS Access - Flatten 1 to Many into concatenated string

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have the following tables in MS Access database.

```
Family                         Member
-----------                    -----------
ID                             MEM_ID
FAMILY_NAME                    FIRST_NAME
                               FAMILY_ID
```

Data:

```
Family
1        Jones
2        Smith


Member
1        John        1
2        Sally        1
3        Suzy        1
4        Billy        2
5        Mary        2
6        Jack        2
```

Trying to figure out the query that returns the following:

```
ID        FAMILY_NAME        FIRST_NAMES
1        Jones                        John, Sally, Suzy
2        Smith                        Billy, Mary, Jack
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

Comment: MS Access is not the best database for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible within Access.

Firstly, you will need to create a VBA function that accepts the FAMILY_ID and returns a concatenated list of members:

```
Public Function fFamailyMember(lngID As Long) As String
    On Error GoTo E_Handle
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rsData As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strSQL  As String
    Set db = DBEngine(0)(0)
    strSQL = "SELECT FIRST_NAME FROM Member " _
        & " WHERE FAMILY_ID=" & lngID _
        & " ORDER BY FIRST_NAME ASC;"
    Set rsData = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    If Not (rsData.BOF And rsData.EOF) Then
        Do
            fFamailyMember = fFamailyMember & rsData!FIRST_NAME & ","
            rsData.MoveNext
        Loop Until rsData.EOF
    End If
    If Right(fFamailyMember, 1) = "," Then fFamailyMember = Left(fFamailyMember, Len(fFamailyMember) - 1)
fExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    rsData.Close
    Set rsData = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    Exit Function
E_Handle:
    MsgBox Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "fFamilyMember", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
    Resume fExit
End Function
```

Now you can create a query based on the FAMILY table and using this function:

```
SELECT F.ID, F.FAMILY_NAME, fFamailyMember(F.ID) AS FIRST_NAMES
FROM Family AS F
```

Note that this query isn't going to be updateable, as the FIRST_NAMES field doesn't really exist. Also, because the query is repeatedly calling this function (which in turn is opening and looping through a recordset), there will be some overhead in processing time.

Regards,

Comment: Where does this function go?  Fairly new to Access.  Is there a standard library for functions across the database?  I've seen places for code in the events.

Comment: Add it to a new module. As the function is declared as `Public` it will be available anywhere within the database.

Comment: Worked great.  Thanks a lot.  Now I'm going to dig in to understand the details of the function.